import statement not recognized by python
i was coding in python, i 'imported' the timeit module, when i tried running
timeit.timeit(stmt,setup,number=100000)
it threw an error stating
NameError: name 'timeit' is not defined
im unable to figure this out is because its not recognizing the import statement.
i tried rewriting it, still didnt recognize it.
my jupyter notebook (its not giving syntax highlighting, and not importing.)
error in question
edit: i just found some really weird fix, all i had to do was write in a new cell?
weird fix?

it doesn't look like you ran the cell with the import, and indeed, that is what the error implies. Did you accidentally make it a markdown cell or something (maybe by accidentally using the shortcut)?

It's hard to tell what could be wrong. In general, timeit is a built-in in Python's standard library, so your program should work with a simple "import timeit".

However, I suspect that your intepreter could be wrong. Make sure to enable it, or configure some sort of virtual environment for your project.
Also make sure your variables "stmt" and "setup" aren't undefined.
Also consider making sure you run your imports in your jupyter notebook first

Overall, worst case I would just restart by making a new venv, copy your code over, and it'll be fixed.

I wrote this. Just because I put it in a list format doesn't mean its ChatGPT or GenAI
